# multiple regexpQuery vs single matchQuery with fielddata enabled

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Let's say i have a Subject entity with a list of Message entities.
I want to be able to retrieve all the "Subjects" that have "Messages" that contain several words (like "elasticsearch" and "data") in their "body" attribute.

I'm using spring data elasticsearch for creating the NativeSearchQuery.

One approach would be to NOT have the fielddata enabled and do several regexp queries like this

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String word : wordsToSearchFor) {
    queryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery(message.body, ".*" + word.toLowerCase() + ".*"));
}
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(queryBuilder).build()
```

Another approach would be to have the fielddata enabled and do a single query, like this

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchQuery("message.body", "elasticsearch data"))
    .build();
```

but from what i've read on the official elastic site, this approach is not encouraged because of high heap memory usage and low hits time: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Which approach would be better in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your use-case, the simple full-text search doesn’t require to enable the `fielddata` on text field(disabled by default) and as you already know it's costly not recommended and instead you should have the `.keyword` field for your `text` field and do the sorting, aggregation on that field.

By looking at your search query, you are not doing the sorting, aggregations hence you shouldn't use the field data. Also, regex queries are expensive and if you can provide your use-case we can offer you a better way to build those queries.

Comment: i will also be doing some sort operations, so i was planning to use the .keyword for those. But my main concern was if multiple regex queries can have an even worse impact on performance than having the fielddata enabled. Also the second approach is not fully functional since i would also need to search for subparts of multiple words. The use case is something like a forum or messenger app

Comment: @sodomark sorry looks like I missed your comment, anyway to answer you questions, you should avoid the regex queries if you can(leading wildcard if you can block that would be great) and your can do sorting, aggregation on keyword fields